# How to setup protractor tests for debugging with Visual studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, testing, protractor

We use:
protractor for e2e tests,
Mocha and Chai,
Node js tools for Visual Studio 2015
Node.js project.
protractor's conf.js looks like this:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'mocha',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['./tests/**/*_test.js'],
    mochaOpts: {
        timeout: 30000 // ms
    }
}
```

All what I need - stop on breakpoints.

Protractor works fine while I run  `protractr conf.js`, but I can't find the way to get to breakpoints inside of IDE.
I read articles, they all are about Visual Studio Code and launch.json or about remote debugging. Both of them looks like not for my common situation.
I also tried `brows.pause()`, `browser.debugger()` or  `deugger;`- no reaction. Tests just run and fails (as expected) the same way as without these commands.
Maybe there is working a configuration for Settings of the Project to let me run protractor's testrs and debug them inside or at least in browkser?

Comment: So it is related to the AngularJS project like the following document, am I right? https://misaxionsoftware.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/angularjs-protractor-visual-studio-super-dry/

Debugging:
                Include node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js into project and Set it as Node.js Startup File
                In project properties, configure Script arguments as protractor.conf.js

Comment: thanks. This is correct. I found this solution later, after my post. You may add it below and I'll mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Artem,

Note: As Eddie's requirement, I just help him add the answer here from his comment.

The solution:

Reference:

https://misaxionsoftware.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/angularjs-protractor-visual-studio-super-dry/

AngularJS Debugging:

(1)Include node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js into project and Set it as Node.js Startup File

(2)In project properties, configure Script arguments as protractor.conf.js